# Mapping Words to Integers using Hashing in C++

Tags: c++, hash

Is there a consistent and widely used package for mapping strings to integers? I am using a data set (Wikipedia) that can possibly have 2.5 billion words and would like a reliable and fast way of mapping words to a unique integer identifier.

Comment: `std::hash<std::string>`?

Comment: I am worried about collision. Have you used it for any large-scale data?

Comment: Surely, even Wikipedia won't have 2.5 billion different words?  It might have 2.5 million different words with all the proper names, etc, but English is reckoned to have about 1 million words in total (Google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=number+of+words+in+dictionary).  The result type of `std::hash<>` is a synonym for `size_t`.  If you have 32-bit `size_t`, there's a moderate chance of collisions; if you have 64-bit `size_t`, there's an very small chance of collisions.

Comment: There's no standard implementation, but the probability of a collision *should* be approaching `1.0/std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max().`.

Comment: @user3639557, `std::has<std::string>` does not make any performance guarantees. An implementation is free to choose any hashing scheme as long as it meets the functional requirements.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: isn't it the probability of collisions related to the Birthday Paradox, so the nominal limit is nearer `1.0 / sqrt(std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max())`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler documentation (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) says:      1.0/std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max(). on my machine 64-bit it is 1/18446744073709551615, which is almost zero, so I think it should be safe to use.

Comment: What about the `java.lang.String#hashCode` implementation: `s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]`?

Comment: The question is tagged by cpp though :)

Comment: @user3639557 the math still fits : )

Comment: @user3639557: that gives the probability that two hashes collide.  The Birthday Paradox says that when you have lots of hashes, a collision occurs (becomes probable) when the total number of hashed values is approximately the square root of the number of possible different hash values.  So, if you have a 32-bit `size_t`, you can start expecting collisions when you have around 2^16 different words to hash (that's just 65,536).  So, with somewhere between 50,000 and 100,000 distinct words, you'll probably have two different words hashing to the same 32-bit value.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I suppose on a 64-bit machine this is quite reasonable to do (2^sqrt(64)=4,294,967,296).

Comment: @user3639557: yes, a 64-bit `size_t` means you need around 4 billion distinct words before you are likely to get collisions.  For the given problem, with 32-bit hashes, it is very probable that there'd be collisions from anywhere near a million distinct words, but with 64-bit hashes, the chances are pretty much negligible (though if there truly are 2.5 billion distinct words — improbable as I consider it — then the 64-bit hash is on the edge of being insufficiently long).

Comment: Incidentally, the Birthday Paradox comes from asking "how many people do you need in a room before two people have the same birthday".  The answer is in the low 20s; 23 is about the 50:50 chance.  The chances that someone has a birthday on a given date is much smaller — or you need many more people in the room before it becomes probable that someone has a birthday on a given date.  But two people sharing the same birthday when the date is not pre-determined is much more probable.

Comment: I think with the birthday thing once you have more than 12 people in the room, it is 100% likely to have at least two people sharing the same birthday "month". It's a derivation of Pigeonhole principle, is it? But it becomes trickier to compute the probability of ANY-two-person sharing a birthday month.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention what collision probability you are willing to accept. With a perfect 64-bit hash you will have a 10^-6 chance of a collision within your 2.5 million words. This is the best you can get with `std::hash` on a 64-bit system. If this is not sufficient you have to use a bigger hash like MD5 (128 bit and a 10^-26 collision chance) or SHA-1 (160 bit and a 10^-35 collision chance). the chance of a collision also depends on the quality of the hash function. you should use a well known cryptographic hash like MD5 or SHA-1 which may contradict your speed requirement.